# Media Player Classic Crashes on Windows 10 on any file

Tags: windows-10, nvidia-geforce, media-player-classic

Media Player Classic Crashes on Windows 10 on any file.

Driver is updated and from nVidia, video card is GTX770.

P.S. Unable to register on https://trac.mpc-hc.org/login

Comment: Where's your crash log or at the minimum, the application crash details from Windows event viewer?

Comment: Isn't this happening at everybody's?

Comment: No.  Working fine here.  Also Windows 10, also using MPC-HC, also using an nVidia video card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can remember, reinstall of MPC helped. I.e. Windows removed/changed some required files.

Answer (score 0):

You can acess:

https://nightly.mpc-hc.org/

for newest Version (build - 1.7.9)

Comment: How are you affiliated with MPC ? What makes you think that build - 1.7.9 is what OP needs ?

Answer (score 0):

In my experiencde, MPC starts crashing everytime I've installed an update of the K Lite Codec Pack. I get the impression there's some fault in the update or install procedure of that codec pack (which MPC is bundled with).

Answer (score -1):

Chances are you are using a 3rd party program to help with the video card management, like EVGA Precision.

Uninstall said program, restart your computer and try watching a video again, hopefully it should've fixed the issue.

If you want to be extra sure, after you restart the computer from uninstalling the 3rd party program, reinstall MPC-HC and restart the computer again.

Comment: Please omit signatures from posts, which is considered noise.  Your usercard is already sufficient.